# Extra white space at the bottom of my webpage?

Tags: css, footer

Every time I am working on a webpage, everything seems to be going fine and then mid-way through creating my CSS document, I wind up with this extra white space below my footer.

It looks as if my background doesn't extend all the way to the bottom of the page, but I would like it to fill from under the header to the very bottom of the landing page.

I am curious if it is just because the site is not live yet or is there something in my code causing this to happen.

The site isn't completely finished, but I want to try and get this solved before moving any further.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Horrorland</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Welcome to Horrorland</h1>
        <h4>Where EVIL Rules and Good CANNOT Exist</h4>
        <nav class="top-bar">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <a href="#">Videos</a>
            <a href="#">News</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <h2>What secrets lie in the places we CANNOT see?</h2>
        <p>Being afraid is a natural part of 
           life.  Human beings cannot comprehend
           things that they cannot explain.  This
           website will detail YOUR stories and 
           bring them to life, giving your fears
           a voice that will hopefully silence them
           in your head.  At the bottom of this
           there is a contact section for you to
           upload any stories you may have via video
           or text and we will create a short post
           explaining what is causing this fear from
           a psychological approach.</p>
    </main>
    <section class="featured">
        <h2>This Weeks Featured Case</h2>
        <a class="witch" href="#"> 
            <img src="images/witch.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    </section>
    <section class="submission">
        <h3>Submit your story here</h3>
        <form method="post" action="mailto:magdosjunk@gmail.com">
            <textarea name="story" id="story" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
        </form> 
    </section>
    <footer>
        <nav class="foot-bar">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <a href="#">Videos</a>
            <a href="#">News</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </nav>
        <h6>&copy; Horrorland LLC 2022 &copy;</h6>
    </footer>
    
</body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body, html {
    color: rgb(148, 11, 11);
    background: url('images/bloody_hands.jpg');
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
    color: rgb(148, 11, 11);
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}


main, section {
    padding: 5px 5px;
}

section h2{
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 54px;
    font-family: fantasy;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: fantasy;
}

h4 {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    
}

h6 {
    font-weight: 900;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

p {
    font-weight: 600;
}


.top-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly; 
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.witch {
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}

.submission {
    text-align: left;
}

.foot-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 60%;
}



#submit {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 150px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    width: 15%;
    height: 10vh;
    transition: 1s;
    
}

#submit:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
    opacity: .7;
}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {

    section a {
        position: relative;
        left: 467px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. What browser are you using? Usually such gaps are a result of uncontrolled margin, check for that inside your footer (h6 prob has the default one).

Comment: This is probably because `h6` has `padding-bottom: 5px;` delete it and check if that solves the problem.

Comment: I tried removing the padding from the h6 and unfortunately that didn't solve it.  I've also been trying to remove and add different CSS options through the developer tools in the browser itself but even if I removed all the CSS I applied, that space never goes away.  I will look into the h6 margin here next.  Thank you both for your suggestions!

Comment: Also I am currently using Microsoft Edge but I usually work in Chrome @Jared.

Comment: If you provide a link to your site, that would help.

Comment: H elements got margin-top|bottom so make sure to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your body or html class

```css
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body, html {
    color: rgb(148, 11, 11);
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
html {
    background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/900');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

header {
    color: rgb(148, 11, 11);
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}


main, section {
    padding: 5px 5px;
}

section h2{
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 54px;
    font-family: fantasy;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: fantasy;
}

h4 {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    
}

h6 {
    font-weight: 900;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

p {
    font-weight: 600;
}


.top-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly; 
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.witch {
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}

.submission {
    text-align: left;
}

.foot-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 60%;
}



#submit {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 150px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    width: 15%;
    height: 10vh;
    transition: 1s;
    
}

#submit:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
    opacity: .7;
}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {

    section a {
        position: relative;
        left: 467px;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Welcome to Horrorland</h1>
        <h4>Where EVIL Rules and Good CANNOT Exist</h4>
        <nav class="top-bar">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <a href="#">Videos</a>
            <a href="#">News</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <h2>What secrets lie in the places we CANNOT see?</h2>
        <p>Being afraid is a natural part of 
           life.  Human beings cannot comprehend
           things that they cannot explain.  This
           website will detail YOUR stories and 
           bring them to life, giving your fears
           a voice that will hopefully silence them
           in your head.  At the bottom of this
           there is a contact section for you to
           upload any stories you may have via video
           or text and we will create a short post
           explaining what is causing this fear from
           a psychological approach.</p>
    </main>
    <section class="featured">
        <h2>This Weeks Featured Case</h2>
        <a class="witch" href="#"> 
            <img src="images/witch.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    </section>
    <section class="submission">
        <h3>Submit your story here</h3>
        <form method="post" action="mailto:magdosjunk@gmail.com">
            <textarea name="story" id="story" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
        </form> 
    </section>
    <footer>
        <nav class="foot-bar">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <a href="#">Videos</a>
            <a href="#">News</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </nav>
        <h6>&copy; Horrorland LLC 2022 &copy;</h6>
    </footer>
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body, html {
    color: rgb(148, 11, 11);
    background: url('images/bloody_hands.jpg');
    max-width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `#submit` `position: relative` style is causing this, with the `bottom: 150px`:

```css
#submit {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 150px;  /* <-------------- */
    background: red;
    color: white;
    width: 15%;
    height: 10vh;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

The button is taking horizontal space after the form, but you are moving it using `relative` position, which leaves the "space" it occupies as-is (the white space below).

I suggestion you to change your code to this:

```css
#submission form {
  position: relative;  /* acts as the button's position container */
}

#submit {
    position: absolute; /* "absolute" does not takes the space like "relative" */
    bottom: 150px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    width: 15%;
    height: 10vh;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

---

#### Live example:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body, html {
    color: rgb(148, 11, 11);
    background: url('images/bloody_hands.jpg');
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
    color: rgb(148, 11, 11);
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}


main, section {
    padding: 5px 5px;
}

section h2{
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 54px;
    font-family: fantasy;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: fantasy;
}

h4 {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    
}

h6 {
    font-weight: 900;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

p {
    font-weight: 600;
}


.top-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly; 
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.witch {
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}

.submission {
    text-align: left;
}

.foot-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 60%;
}

#submission form {
  position: relative; 
}

#submit {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 150px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    width: 15%;
    height: 10vh;
    transition: 1s;
}

#submit:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
    opacity: .7;
}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {

    section a {
        position: relative;
        left: 467px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Horrorland</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Welcome to Horrorland</h1>
        <h4>Where EVIL Rules and Good CANNOT Exist</h4>
        <nav class="top-bar">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <a href="#">Videos</a>
            <a href="#">News</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <h2>What secrets lie in the places we CANNOT see?</h2>
        <p>Being afraid is a natural part of 
           life.  Human beings cannot comprehend
           things that they cannot explain.  This
           website will detail YOUR stories and 
           bring them to life, giving your fears
           a voice that will hopefully silence them
           in your head.  At the bottom of this
           there is a contact section for you to
           upload any stories you may have via video
           or text and we will create a short post
           explaining what is causing this fear from
           a psychological approach.</p>
    </main>
    <section class="featured">
        <h2>This Weeks Featured Case</h2>
        <a class="witch" href="#"> 
            <img src="images/witch.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    </section>
    <section class="submission">
        <h3>Submit your story here</h3>
        <form method="post" action="mailto:magdosjunk@gmail.com">
            <textarea name="story" id="story" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
        </form> 
    </section>
    <footer>
        <nav class="foot-bar">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <a href="#">Videos</a>
            <a href="#">News</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </nav>
        <h6>&copy; Horrorland LLC 2022 &copy;</h6>
    </footer>
    
</body>
</html>
```